# Does Node JS have an apply like function similar to python

Tags: node.js

With Pandas, say I wanted to multiply each number in a dataframe series by 2, I could write something like

```
f = lambda x: x*2
df.col.apply(f)
```

With Node, say I want to encode each url in an array. Is there a similar function. I'm wondering if the following will work:

```
array.map(encodeURIComponent)
```

Or, do I need to do the following:

```
const encodeUrls = (url)=>{return encodeURIComponent(url)}
```

Comment: It is better do not tag pandas..and python

Comment: apply just runs once it looks like. it'd need to be used with a loop to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map) will do the work.

```js
const urls = ['https://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab', 'http://www.example.org/a file with spaces.html'];

console.log(urls.map(encodeURI))
```

You can read about the difference between [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/encodeURIComponent) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/4796844